# Оформить форму в WinForms с ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброго времени суток. Написал приложение "электронная очередь" одну версию сделал на WPF вторую надо на WinForms. Времени в обрез разбираться, с ходу не получилось.
В итоге нужно оформить форму на которой во весь экран будет ListView с 2-мя столбцами. На картинке изображено как надо.

[image: ВИД ОКНА]

Т.е. по сути нужно заголовок колонок оформить так как изображено с ним у меня не выходит.

Comment: В комментариях, осмелюсь покритиковать дизайн. Когда будет много строк, сложно будет сходу различать где какая, без границ и при сильном разнесении как на скриншоте. Если линии, так не милы, можно хотя бы через одну строчку менять цвет текста. Опять же в DataGridView для этого, есть встроенное свойство AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle

Answer (score 2):

Советую выбрать элемент управления DataGridView, вместо ListView. Он позволяет настраивать отдельно стили ячеек, заголовков строк и столбцов. А это удобно в Вашем случае. Для ListView, пришлось бы играться с событиями отрисовки, что не удобно. 
Для ListView надо
`OwnerDraw` задать `True`.
Подписаться на `DrawColumnHeader` и `DrawItem`, работать с графикой:
`e.Graphics.DrawBackground` и
`e.Graphics.DrawString`

В DataGridView Вам будут интересны следующие свойства:

`Dock` задайте `Fill`, чтобы элемент управления растянулся на всё свободное пространство.

`RowHeadersVisble` задайте `False`, чтобы убрать заголовки строк.

`CellBorderStyle` и
  `ColumnHeadersBorderStyle` задайте `None`, чтобы убрать границы.

Свойства `DefaultCellStyle` и `ColumnHeaderDefaultCellStyle` позволят вам отредактировать нужные шрифты, цвет текста и фона.

Comment: Спасибо. А не могли бы вы подсказать как сделать с ListView. т.к. система заполнения списка уже работает и не хотелось бы ее трогать.

Comment: @Aldmi, поправил ответ